# Getting status code 415 for Rest API URI Via Rest Assured but working fine via Rest Client

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Getting 415 error in rest assured. Same URI is working fine with Rest client in browser. From Rest client i am getting response code 200.

```
public static Response response;
public static String jsonAsString;


@BeforeClass
public static void setupURL()
{
    // here we setup the default URL and API base path to use throughout the tests
    RestAssured.baseURI = "######url##########";
    //RestAssured.basePath = "/api/v1";
    RestAssured.authentication = basic("password", "password");
    Header acceptJson = new Header("content-type", "application/json");
    //RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON);
    RestAssured.given().header(acceptJson);
}

@Test
public void getImageThroughImageid(){
    RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
    Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET, "/images/imageid");
    System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());

}
```

Comment: I added this in request now it's working fine.
contentType("application/json")

Answer (score 2):

Need to add Both

```
.header("Content-Type","application/json" )
 .header("Accept","application/json" )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong header for your accept. `content-type` tells the server what request body you're sending; you want to use `accept` to tell the server what type of response you want.

Comment: I tried "accept" "application/json" also but getting same result

Comment: Did you remove the bad `content-type` as well?

Comment: Yes I removed content-type

Comment: If you're still not getting it to match the browser response, you should try sending the same headers as your browser is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EncoderConfig encoderConfig = RestAssured.config().getEncoderConfig()
                      .appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false);

RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig);
```

In my case problem was caused by rest assured, which appends "charset" to request header `"content-type=application/json"`.
Such request header may be refused when the server is principled and strict comply RFC 7159

Answer (score 0):

Simply update rest-assured dependency & try to post a payload.

Older rest-assured library appends charset after 'content-type' even if you explicitly set it "application/json".

```
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Authorization=Bearer --token**
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

but new rest-assured library will furnish header this way..

> Headers:      Accept=*/*
> Authorization=Bearer --token**
> Content-Type=application/json

I updated below dependency which resolved my issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```